# Not able to scrape the description properly using Beautiful Soup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am web-scraping this link : https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/smart-earn-credit-card/?linknav=in-amex-cardshop-allcards-learn-SmartEarnCreditCard-carousel
using bs4 and python.

I am basically grabbing the key benefits from that website using the following code.

```
link = 'https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/smart-earn-credit-card/?linknav=in-amex-cardshop-allcards-learn-SmartEarnCreditCard-carousel'
html = urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

details = []

for span in soup.select(".why-amex__subtitle span"):
    details.append(f'{span.get_text(strip=True)}: {span.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True)}')



print(details)
```

**Output**

```
['Accelerated Earn Rate: Earn 10X Membership Rewards® Points2on your spending on Flipkart and Uber and earn 5X Membership Rewards Points2on Amazon, Swiggy, BookMyShow and more.', 'Welcome Bonus: Rs. 500 cashback as Welcome Gift on eligible spends1of Rs. 10,000 in the first 90 days of Cardmembership', 'Renewal Fee Waiver: Get a renewal fee waiver on eligible spends3of Rs.40,000 and above in the previous year of Cardmembership', 'AMERICAN EXPRESS EMI: Convert purchases into']
```

The last item in this list is not scraped properly, it is incomplete.
Because there is a hyperlink in the middle of the text.

Below is the html code corresponding to that problem:

```
<div class="why-amex__col"><span class="icons  why-amex__lrgIcon icon-Amex-Icons-2016-85"></span><h4 class="why-amex__subtitle"><div><span>AMERICAN EXPRESS EMI</span></div></h4><div class="why-amex__copy"><div class="description_text"><div><span>Convert purchases into </span><a href="https://www.americanexpress.com/india/membershiprewards/cardmember_offers/viewmore.html" target="_blank">EMI</a><span> at the point of sale with an interest rate as low as 12% p.a. and zero foreclosure charges</span></div></div></div></div>
```

I'd like to get the full description of the last item without missing out the text.

Answer (score 1):

Just append the innerHTML into `details` and then loop through the tags to construct your text.

Something like:

```py
texts = []
for i, detail in enumerate(details):

    texts.append('')
    for tag in detail.findChildren(recursive=False):

        texts[i] += tag.get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hari\PycharmProjects\Card_Prj\buffer.py", line 31, in <module>
    for tag in detail.findChildren(recursive=False):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findChildren'

Comment: Yeah, the error is telling you that you are appending strings into ``details``. You need to append ``bs4`` objects so you can use ``findChildren``.